# GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:467:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "voaacenc"

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, gstreamer

When trying to execture a gstreamer project, I have said error preventing me to do so.

[image: gstreamer error screenshot]

- **Operating System**: MacOS BigSur 11.3 ( Apple M1 Silicon )
- **Python Version**: 3.6.7
- **Installed packages**: `gstreamer gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-plugins-base gst-python gst-libav`
- **Is the Project running on another system ?**: Yes, on Nvidia Jetson Nanos, with said packages installed
- **`gst-inspect-1.0 voaacenc` result**: [image: gst-inspect-1.0 voaacenc]

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall everything, tried with Homebrew M1 & Intel, manually installed gstreamer packages, I've even manually added `voaacenc.h` to the gst-plugins-bad package folder, no luck.

I've ran out of options, and the existing answers on Stack do not resolve my issue. Any idea ?